# FFMPEG shows bitrate=N/A and doesn't send anything

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to relay an stream from one rtsp url to another without recoding using this command:

> `ffmpeg 
>   -rtsp_transport tcp 
>   -fflags nobuffer 
>   -re
>   -i rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/[stream_name] 
>   -vcodec copy
>   -an 
>   -f rtsp rtsp://yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/[new_stream_name]`

But FFMPEG doesn't stream anything and stats shows bitrate=N/A

This is the exact output that i get:

`ffmpeg version 4.1.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/    Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from
'rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/[stream_name]':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.318111, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 944x1080, 22 fps, 22 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Output #0, rtsp, to 
'rtsp://yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/[new_stream_name]':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 944x1080, q=2-31, 22 fps, 22 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help`

> `frame=  113 fps= 32 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:06.77 bitrate=N/A speed=1.92x`

Although when i change output stream container to 'flv' and protocol to 'rtmp' it works.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To have stream accessible you need to publish it to a streaming server that supports RTSP input (like Wowza SE) and that usually also involves publishing credentials like:
rtsp://user:password@yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/[new_stream_name]

You can test re-streaming with this tool https://videonow.live/broadcast-ip-camera-or-stream/ that can also publish it in a HTML5 accessible format like HLS.

Comment: The server I am publishing to supports rtsp. Also, In my case, I have turned off the source authentication at the server that's why no credentials in the output url.